# AzureMap Error:atlas.min.js:55 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'defaultStyle')

Tags: typeerror

I am getting AzureMap error and seeing this error, can you help me to fix this error?
I do not see any issue to see AzureMap, its working fine but not sure why its giving me this error.

Here is my code for AzureMap.

```
const AzureMap = ({ azureMapKey, selectedSite }) => {
  const mapNodeRef = useRef();
  const isNavExpanded = useSelector(commonSelectors.getIsNavigationExpanded);

  const initializeMap = () => {
    const mapNode = mapNodeRef && mapNodeRef.current;
    const longitude =
      !isNullEmptyOrUndefined(selectedSite?.longitude) &&
      parseFloat(selectedSite?.longitude);
    const latitude =
      !isNullEmptyOrUndefined(selectedSite?.latitude) &&
      parseFloat(selectedSite?.latitude);

    if (!mapNode || !selectedSite) {
      return false;
    }

    const map = new atlas.Map(mapNode, {
      center: [longitude, latitude],
      view: 'auto',
      zoom: 10,
      authOptions: {
        authType: 'subscriptionKey',
        subscriptionKey: azureMapKey
      }
    });

    map.setStyle({
      autoResize: true,
      showLogo: false,
      showFeedbackLink: false
    });

    map.events.add('ready', function() {
      // Create a HTML marker and add it to the map.
      map.markers.add(
        new atlas.HtmlMarker({
          htmlContent: atlas.getImageTemplate('pin'),
          color: '#1471DA',
          anchor: 'top-left',
          pixelOffset: [-5, -30],
          position: [longitude, latitude]
        })
      );
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    initializeMap();
  }, [selectedSite?.siteId]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(initializeMap, 200);
  }, [isNavExpanded]);

  return (
    <div
      ref={mapNodeRef}
      className="bve-map-container"
      data-testid="azure-map"
    />
  );
};

export default AzureMap;
```

this is error I am seeing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBXzm.png)